# How to combine text and variables in fastcgi_param?

Tags: nginx

[tldr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_long%2C_didn%27t_read): how do I randomly mix text and variables in the value part of `fastcgi_params`? In particular adding spaces as text between variables, doesn't work with or without `"` or `'`.

### long version

The [fastcgi_para docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param) reads

> A value can contain text, variables, and their combination.

Does not link or specify explicitly what the text format is or what the combination format is.

### what do I do

I am trying to add four spaces between two variables in order to understand the 'expression format' used in `fastcgi_param`. I get errors. Here are relevant parts from `nginx.conf` with line numbers:

#### try 1 with apostrophe `'`

```
78: fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root'    '$fastcgi_script_name;
82: # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
```

produces

```
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "s" in <nginx.conf>:82
```

#### try 2 (bare)

Another try

```
78: fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root    $fastcgi_script_name;
```

produces

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "$fastcgi_script_name" in <nginx.conf>:78
```

#### try 3 with double quotse `"`

If I use `"` like this:

```
78: fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root"    "$fastcgi_script_name;
```

the error I get is:

```
nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in <nginx.conf>:128
```

If I simply do

```
78: fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

as usual, it works, *so I believe there is no other error in my* `nginx.conf`.

Tried to look up the [source](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c) but due to its generalized nature, I couldn't yet find where the parse and variable substitution is actually done.

### question

How do I mix text and variables in a free-form way with nginx, in particular in the value part of `fastcgi_param`?

I am using **nginx 1.2.5**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already answered on [nginx mailing list](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2014-February/042437.html), try this:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  "$document_root    $fastcgi_script_name";
```

or this:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  '$document_root    $fastcgi_script_name';
```

If a parameter includes special characters, the whole parameter
should be enclosed in single or double quotes.